# dynamic dropdown select not entering value to db on submit

Tags: php, html

Im having issues with data not being entered into the db. I have a form with 5 inputs and a select The drop down select is a dynamic list fro the db. When the form is submitted nothing is entered in the db for the campaign_owner columns. I have the values="" which I think is the problem, but I also tried

```
<option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option>
```

yet that doesn't help.The dropdown shows the data I want and allows you to select it on the page it just doesn't submit it and I dont know why.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
  <label class="control-label" ><?php echo $entry_owner; ?></label>
  <select name="user-list" id="user-list">
    <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `<option value='"<?php echo $user['username']; ?>"'>` need single quotes at ends

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that doesn't seem to fix the issue, but Im sure you are right. Could you please tell me why the double quotes aren't enough in this situation and why the single quotes are required

Comment: Actually I misread the way you're doing it, scratch that sorry.

Comment: are you submitting data using  from or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML forms work with the input/select/textarea etc. names. Your select is named "user-list" which means that when submitted it will be under the key `user-list`. You'll need to map that to the campaign_owner column.